# Google Adword API

Tags: google-ads-api

I am pretty new to AdWord API, I am looking to associate specific Ad with each conversion. Is it possible to query conversion data using Google AdWord API for specific unique Sales Invoice Id. Also, I am looking to know the cost for that particular conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get these details for an AdWords account, but not for a sales invoice id. AdWords API currrently doesn't support anything related to billing, including invoices.

See http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/appendix/reports.html for the list of available reports. You could run one or more reports to get the necessary details.

I also recommend asking your AdWords API questions on the official forum at http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/ in the future. The community is quite active and members of the AdWords API team regularly answer questions on the forum.